# Intergrating (ian coopers) Brighter with StructureMap

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap, brighter

I am jsut getting to grips with the basics of StructureMap (IoC) and am trying to intergrate the Demo of Brighter which can be found here

https://iancooper.github.io/Paramore/QuickStart.html

With Structuremap within an MVC project.

The issue I am having is working out what to pass into the Structuremap Object factory on build, it is returning

I currently have the following error

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in StructureMap.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
```

Factory Handler

```
public class SimpleHandlerFactory : IAmAHandlerFactory
    {
        public IHandleRequests Create(Type handlerType)
        {
            return new GreetingCommandHandler();
        }

        public void Release(IHandleRequests handler)
        {

        }
    }
```

The CommandHandler

```
  public class GreetingCommandHandler : RequestHandler<GreetingCommand>
    {
        public override GreetingCommand Handle(GreetingCommand command)
        {
            Debug.Print("This is the trace for the command :  {0}", command.Name);
            return base.Handle(command);
        }
    }
```

And my Structuremap Dependency Scope

```
   public IHandleRequests<T> GetExecutorFor<T>() where T : class, IRequest
        {
            return this.Container.GetAllInstances<IHandleRequests<T>>().FirstOrDefault(); // GetInstance() throws exception if more than one found
        }
```

And then on the IoC.cs

```
    public static IContainer Initialize() {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                    {
                        x.Scan(scan =>
                                {
                                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                });
                   //  x.For<IHandleRequests<IRequest>>().Use<IHandleRequests<IRequest>>();
// So this is where I was going wrong I should of been doing 
 x.For<IHandleRequests<GreetingCommand>>().Use<GreetingCommandHandler>();
                    });
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Martyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve GreetingCommandHandler you would have to register that in your IContainer specifically, because it will not resolve using DefaultConventions.

```
For<IHandleRequests<GreetingCommand>().Use<GreetingCommandHandler>();
```

Should work for you.

For all other concrete implementations, you would have to do the same.

Comment: Perfect @pedro that is exactly what was needed, :D was just being a bit thick after a long weekend